# skip default luma images generation during static content deployment in magento cloud

Tags: magento2, static-content-deploy, magento2-cloud

I have a requirement where I need to skip the images that were generated by the static-content: deploy in Magento.

In my local and the test environments have --no-images option. But how can I implement this in the Magento cloud environment? Please note that I need to compile the luma store theme but not the images of the luma store.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below command to deploy particular theme static contents only

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy  --theme Vendor/yourtheme
```

and you can also exclude particular theme using below command replace Magento/backend with the theme which you want to exclude

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --exclude-theme Magento/backend
```

Comment: But how can I do the same in the magneto cloud...